# PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So I updated my Parse SDK to the latest version and Xcode shows a bug that previously was fine.

the bug is :

> cannot invoke 'geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground' with an argument list of type '((PFGeoPoint!, NSError!) -> Void)'

```
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint:PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if geoPoint != nil {

            var geoPointLong = geoPoint.longitude
            var geoPointLat = geoPoint.latitude
            var currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude: geoPointLat, longitude: geoPointLong)

            var query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
            query.whereKey("postsLocation", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinKilometers: 5.0 )
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                for object in objects {

                    self.jobPostedArray.addObject(object)
                }

                self.myTableView.reloadData()
                self.refresher.endRefreshing()
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think with the nullable annotation changes that have been made with v1.7.1 (?) of the Parse SDK the block parameters are no longer forced unwrapped - they're optional. If you change your block signature to:

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  ...
}
```

it should work. Or, you could omit the types altogether because the compiler can infer them:

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { geoPoint, error in
  ...
}
```